# Google tells me that http://mydomain.de.whoisbucket.com/ is not indexed

Tags: google-search-console

I got a report from Google Search console (sc-noreply@google.com):

```
Page indexing issues detected in http://sprechcomputer.de/

To the owner of http://sprechcomputer.de/:

Search Console has identified that your site is affected by 1 Page indexing issue(s). The following issues were found on your site. We recommend that you fix these issues when possible to enable the best experience and coverage in Google Search.

Top issues

    Page with redirect

Fix Page indexing issues
```

When I open search console, it says that 4 days ago, my URL was not indexed anymore.

However, I did not change anything.

It offers "INSPECT URL" and "TEST ROBOTS.TXT BLOCKING".

I click "TEST ROBOTS.TXT BLOCKING", and it tells me that I don't have a robots.txt
I click "INSPECT URL", and it shows this:

```
Referring page
http://sprechcomputer.de.whoisbucket.com/
http://www.whoisbucket.com/view/sprechcomputer.de
```

This is the only anomaly that I can see.

These are not my domains. Is this a bug in Search Console?

What is the problem here?

Also, none of my pages are indexed, according to this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Those are some pages that link to your site. Your site is indexed. There's nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Selcuk I don't think you are right. I will post a screenshot that says that none of my pages at sprechcomputer.de are indexed.

Comment: Have you ever tried searching for "sprechcomputer" on Google? Your site is the number one result. It's clearly indexed.

Comment: @Selcuk Actually, I did not. Thanks for telling me, but still I would like to find out what causes google to tell me that it's not indexed. It's my experience that problems don't go away by ignoring them, especially when it's coming from Google.

Comment: This is less of a coding question and more something for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.